Group velocity, phase velocity and signal velocity for axion like particles
In dark matter models of axion-like particles (ALPs), sometimes we get the field
$$\phi=2\phi_0\sin(m_\phi c^2 t/\hbar)\cos(k_\phi x)$$
This is like an stationary field with amplitude $\phi_0$ (in m/s if $\rho=E/V$ is such as $A_0=\sqrt{2G\hbar^2\rho}/m_\phi c^2$), and $k_\phi=p/\hbar=m_\phi c/\hbar$. The field above gives a phase velocity $\omega_\phi/k_\phi=c=v_p$ from the waveform using natural units. Being a massive field, the group velocity should be
$$v_g=\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial p}=\dfrac{pc^2}{\sqrt{p^2c^2+(m_\phi c^2)^2}}$$
However, I can not see the general relation $v_pv_g=c^2$ being valid here UNLESS $m_\phi=0$ exactly, that is NOT the case (the mass is tiny but not zero in these models). Byt the other hand, if we define the phase velocity as $\omega(k)/k=E(p)/p$, we get
$$v_p=\dfrac{E(p)}{p}=\sqrt{c^2+\dfrac{E_\phi^2}{p^2}}$$
and $v_gv_p=c^2$ is right, BUT then I get problems to interpret the amplitude $\phi_0$ as a propagation field speed of the dark matter. Moreover, the limit $\lim_{m_\phi\rightarrow 0}\phi(x=0)$ is a linear growing function of time, something it seems hard to fit to observations.
Question: what are the right interpretations of the speeds ($\phi_0, v_p, v_g, c$) of this ALP dark matter model? The questions I want to be answered is how and what is the velocity we measure experimentally for this type of models. I would have said the group velocity, but after watching the field amplitude (and the "phase velocity" in the limit of massless field) I got confused. And I do know there are different ideas to measure this "dark matter wind"...So I am interested.
Remark: Short proof of $v_gv_p=c^2$ in special relativity can be done
$$v_pv_g=\dfrac{E(p)}{p}\dfrac{dE(p)}{dp}=\dfrac{d((E(p))^2}{d(p^2)}=\dfrac{dE^2(p^2)}{d(p^2)}=c^2$$
Remark (II): The question I did is related to the fact really to the speed of the dark matter wind of these models. What we measure? The amplitude oscillation we estimate from other kind of models or the group velocity (almost c)? If the field is almost massless, then its speed is almost c, but dark matter particles are usually supposed to propagate at non-relativistic speeds!

In units where $\hbar = c = 1$, the general rules are $E^2 = p^2 + m^2$, $v_p = E/p$, and $v_g = dE/dp$. Maybe you got confused because the first equation you wrote down is not exact -- it's just an approximation valid for $p \ll m$.

I guess a little bit of that, but yet, I can not get what are the right interpretation of the limits and speeds in this kind of model...

@knzhou what about $\phi_0$ and its relation with $v_g, v_p, c$? That gets me confused too...

I don't think $v_p$ is a particularly meaningful quantity, so it's not worth paying attention to at all. Of course $v_g$ has the usual meaning of the speed of a wavepacket. Besides that, I'm not sure what you're confused about. In the limit $m \to 0$, the axion field indeed is linearly growing in time, because the field has no potential and so travels with uniform velocity in field space.

@knzhou Such linear growing field, couldn't it close the Universe and collapse it in the future? Of course, we have dark energy, but if the field grows linearly with time it could be dangerous for QFT, or not? I am confused since if I make $\omega/k=c$ despite of being a massive field. And I am puzzled because of the amplitude of the field, with dimensions of speed if $\rho$ is mass density instead of energy density: what is that field velocity-like amplitude? Doe sit means that even when "stationary" the fluctuations of the field are another kind of "speed"?

In general, I would recommend setting $\hbar = c = 1$ everywhere, so that mass density is the same thing as energy density; otherwise you'll just have a lot of annoying factors to keep track of. The universe's expansion is governed by the field's stress-energy, not the field's value. When a field is massless, it can have an enormous value without a large associated stress-energy.
